# Error deploying Java Web application in Wildfly server 20.0.1

Tags: maven, jboss, wildfly, java-ee-8

I am trying to deploy a java web application that connect to files .war and .jar, the principal module is a .ear that connect to the others and i specified that in the Application.xml file, but when i start the server and the application try to up, says that it doesn't find the modules although the modules are in the deployment folder.

WildFly server 20.0.1
JDK 8
Maven 3.8.0

[This how i have the files in the deployment folder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2W3A.png)

[This is where a have de application.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ziLq.png)

This is the content of my application.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_7.xsd"
             version="7">

    <!-- Descripción de la aplicación empresarial -->
    <display-name>s2-vital-ear</display-name>

    <!-- Módulo JAR -->
    <module>
        <java>s2-commons-2.28.1.jar</java>
    </module>


    <!-- Módulo WAR -->
    <module>
        <web>
            <web-uri>s2-enlace-web-2.28.1.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>/s2-vital-web</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>

</application>
```

this is the error that generate the file application.xml

```
17:26:40,495 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.4.1.Final (Apache CXF 3.3.6)
17:26:40,522 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."s2-vital-ear-2.28.1.ear".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."s2-vital-ear-2.28.1.ear".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "s2-vital-ear-2.28.1.ear"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:189)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0031: Unable to process modules in application.xml for EAR ["/C:/Users/andreacamacho/instaladores/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/bin/content/s2-vital-ear-2.28.1.ear"], module file s2-commons-2.28.1.jar not found
        at org.jboss.as.ee.structure.EarStructureProcessor.deploy(EarStructureProcessor.java:187)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
        ... 8 more
```

Comment: Is the `s2-commons-2.28.1.jar` in your EAR?

Comment: Yes, it is. but says that it does not found it

Comment: Actually, that path looks really weird. How are you deploying your EAR?